# How to refactor my concrete class to an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, refactoring, automated-refactoring

What is the best way to refactor the following C# code to a new Interface?

Old:

```
Aaaa MyMethod(Aaaa a) {
  Aaaa a2 = new Aaaa();
  return a2;
}
```

New:

```
IAaaa MyMethod(IAaaa a) {
  IAaaa a2 = new Aaaa();
  return a2;
}
```

Be aware that **new Aaaa()** should be the same after replacing and notice that I want to refactor my complete solution not only one file.

Are there any tools?

---

I'm able to extract an interface of a class with VisualStudio.

I want a script/tool like the following:

- replace "new Aaaa()" against "new A_SAVE_aaa()"
- replace "Aaaa" against "IAaaa"
- replace "new A_SAVE_aaa() against "new Aaaa()"

Comment: "Are there any tools?" ReSharper Refactor/Extract.../Extract Interface?

Comment: An interface is a contract, it can't contain implementation, so you can't refactor a concrete class to interface. You can define your interface with set of methods from your concrete class and then implement that interface in your class.

Comment: @Habib: "new Aaaa()" should be untouched. But after some years of hard work I want to program against an interface because I need some polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Unfortunatly I have no ReSharper license.

Comment: @koalabruder asking for a tool is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up here because I googled "refactor concrete class to an interface" wondering if anybody had written about it.
I was particularly interested in C++ refactors because a way I'd tried that was clunky was to create the interface, convert some methods over, and convert more methods as I needed them.
But a way that worked swimmingly was I renamed Aaaa to AaaaXXX and made it inherit from a new Aaaa which was the interface. (In C++ I now had to declare all the AaaaXXX methods "override.") The few places in the code that created an Aaaa now had to create an AaaaXXX instead - I leaned on the compiler to find those.
Once that compiled, ran, and passed its unit tests it was simple to rename Aaaa to IAaaa and AaaaXXX to Aaaa.
Sorry, don't know if there are any tools, but this two-step approach, particularly in C++ which isn't good at renaming symbols, seemed better than a one-step.